# Why doesn't PDFKit always close the file it's writing in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKit to create a PDF on demand in an electron application.  I wrote a function in my preload.js file, which is called from javascript in the main application.  It successfully creates the PDF, but about half the time it holds the PDF open until I close the application - at which point it finishes writing the PDF and closes the file.

preload.js:

```
window.makePDF = function(title, subtitle, table, svg) {

  const doc = new PDFDocument();
  const writestream = createWriteStream(path);
  doc.pipe(writestream);
  
  doc
    .font('Helvetica')
    .fontSize(16)
    .text(title, {align: 'center'})

  // More doc.text() here to fill in the document
    
  writestream.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('done writing to file ' + path);
  });
    
  doc.end();
}
```

In the main application:

```
window.makePDF(siteName, subtitle, table, svg)
```